# Ruby on Rails:How to validate that id is existed in other columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a column that require whether the id of the User is exist or not 
My table has these column (id is auto generated)

Table name: users

```
id              :integer         not null, primary key
first_name      :string
last_name       :string           
email           :string           
sponsor_id      :integer
created_at      :datetime        not null
updated_at      :datetime        not null
password_digest :string
```

Every value of the `User.sponsor_id` must be exist in `User.id` column. Right now, I have this validation for the `sponsor_id`:

> validates :sponsor_id,numericality:{ only_integer: true },  presence:
>   true

I tried this code to make the sponsor_id check whether the id is exist or not

> ```
> #Validate that the user is exist in the data
> def validate_sponsor_id
>     errors.add(:sponsor_id,"is not exist")   if User.find_by(id: self.sponsor_id).id ==nil?
> end
> ```

Can anyone help me? thank you

Comment: I cannot get what you mean by the first sentence. (Leaving aside the grammatical mistakes, it still does not make any sense to me.) "Whether ..." is not something you can require.

Comment: did you mean id  and sponsor_id must have same values??

Answer (score 0):

You must realize that validations only occur on the saving of an object; you're trying to invoke them for when you load an object, which won't work.

If you wanted to do this on its own, you'd want to use [`exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class)

```
User.exists? sponsor_id: self.sponsor.id
```

---

However, it seems to me that you need something different.

Specifically, I guess it means that every user needs to have a `sponsor`, otherwise their membership is invalid.

To do this, I would use the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :sponsor, class_name: "User"
   validates :sponsor, presence: true
end
```

This will mean that every single time you create or update a `User` object, it will look for a `sponsor` object, which incidentally means that it will check `sponsor_id`.

The other important factor to consider is that if you use a [self referential join](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) -- whereby you reference the same model with an association. This will give you the ability to associate a "sponsor" with a user in the `User` model (which is I think what you want).

Comment: Hey this is what I want. I will try and get back to you!

Comment: Hey I just tried your code. It works really well! However, in my project the 'User.first' doesn't need a sponsor_id. How can I make this? Thank you

Comment: Can you give me more context -- what is `User.first` exactly? What data is stored in there?

Comment: I tried your code but there is one problem I wrote this unit test 
`   test "15. the sponsor_id must be the existing id" do
     @user2.sponsor_id = 1000
     assert_not @user2.valid?
end `
And it gave me error that the user2.valid but that id doesn't exist why is that ?

Comment: My validation works on the sponsor object, not the `sponsor_id`. If you wanted `sponsor_id` validation, you'd need to include a separate validation like `validate :sponsor_id_valid` `def sponsor_id_valid User.exists? sponsor_id: sponsor_id end`

Comment: I use the `db/seeds.rb` and my first user is 
 `@user1= User.create(first_name: "Test",
               last_name: "User",
               email: "test@user.com",
               password: "password",
               password_confirmation: "password",
               sponsor_id: nil)`
Then I use
 `       @user2=User.new(
        first_name: "Test2",
        last_name: "User2", 
        email: "user2@test.com",
        sponsor_id: @user.id,
        password:"foobar",
        password_confirmation:"foobar")`
to be a second user

Comment: You can get the test to work by setting the `sponsor` object like `user = User.new` `user2 = User.find 3` `user.sponsor = user2` `user.valid?`

Comment: Oh I got it. so instead of making a column of sponsor_id, I should store a sponsor user instead right?

Comment: nooooooooo. You have sponsor_id properly set up. All I was saying that the validation I wrote is for `sponsor` as an object, not `sponsor_id`. This is why if you set `sponsor_id` directly, it is validated regardless of whether `Sponsor` exists or not.

Comment: I see but test number 15 when I tried to assert the id that doesnt exist the test still pass. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hey I got it thank you so much. Right now I have the problem that I need an additional exception which stated that the  first user don't need to have a sponsor id (because he is the first user)  how can I do that?  Thank you!!  You are awesome

Comment: Hey, I tried to post my code but it is too long. Anyway I've tried your code and what happen is that it give me this error when I tried to 
`rake db:seed`
`rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Sponsor can't be blank`

Comment: `class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :sponsor, class_name: "User"
  validates :sponsor, presence:true 
  validate :sponsor_id_valid

  def sponsor_id_valid
     if self.sponsor_id.blank? && User.count!=User.first
    errors.add(:sponsor_id, "is not exist")
    end
  end
end`
@Rich Peck

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you want to self joins table(relationship within the same model). You can easily do this without this validation like below.

```
//Find a user who is going to be sponsor
@sponsoruser = User.find_by(id: someid)

//Find a user who is accepting a sponsor
@user = User.find_by(id: someid)

@user.update_attributes(sponsor_id: @sponsoruser.id) if @sponsoruser.id?
```

Comment: Hey this is great! I will get back to you when I tried it :)

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand, sponsor_id is an id of another user. You can do this:

In your User model write:

```
belongs_to :sponsor, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :sponsor_id
```

And then instead of updating or creating a User by giving it the sponsor_id you can do something like:

```
User.create(sponsor: User.last #or something #more attributes)
```

The last will fail if you don't give a valid user as a sponsor